# Sorting in XML via XSLT

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, grouping

I have this XML output

```
<root>
    <row>
        <Additional_Information>
            <OrgID>SO_000048333</OrgID>
            <ParentOrgID>SO_000337522</ParentOrgID>
        </Additional_Information>
        <Additional_Information>
            <OrgID>SO_000001780</OrgID>
            <ParentOrgID>TOP_MOST_ORG</ParentOrgID>
        </Additional_Information>
        <Additional_Information>
            <OrgID>SO_000041599</OrgID>
            <ParentOrgID>SO_000001780</ParentOrgID>
        </Additional_Information>
        <Additional_Information>
            <OrgID>SO_3-23773</OrgID>
            <ParentOrgID>SO_000253386</ParentOrgID>
        </Additional_Information>
        <Additional_Information>
            <OrgID>SO_000305947</OrgID>
            <ParentOrgID>SO_000001780</ParentOrgID>
        </Additional_Information>
        <Additional_Information>
            <OrgID>SO_000121212</OrgID>
            <ParentOrgID>SO_000046509</ParentOrgID>
        </Additional_Information>
        <Additional_Information>
            <OrgID>SO_000034169</OrgID>
            <ParentOrgID>SO_000305947</ParentOrgID>
        </Additional_Information>
        <Additional_Information>
            <OrgID>SO_000033807</OrgID>
            <ParentOrgID>SO_000048333</ParentOrgID>
        </Additional_Information>
        <Additional_Information>
            <OrgID>SO_000337522</OrgID>
            <ParentOrgID>TOP_MOST_ORG</ParentOrgID>
        </Additional_Information>
        <Additional_Information>
            <OrgID>SO_000030934</OrgID>
            <ParentOrgID>SO_000033807</ParentOrgID>
        </Additional_Information>
        <Additional_Information>
            <OrgID>SO_000253386</OrgID>
            <ParentOrgID>SO_000030934</ParentOrgID>
        </Additional_Information>
        <Additional_Information>
            <OrgID>SO_000046509</OrgID>
            <ParentOrgID>SO_000001780</ParentOrgID>
        </Additional_Information>
    </row>
</root>
```

OrgIDs/ParentOrgIDs has 2 formats: SO_XXXXXXXXX and SO_3-XXXXX

I am using XSLT 2.0

I want it to be sorted like this
SO_000001780 (2nd level in the hierarchy, those with ParentOrgID = TOP_MOST_ORG)
-SO_000041599 (child of the 2nd level)
-SO_000046509 (another child of the 2nd level)
--SO_000121212  (child of the 3rd level in hierarchy)
-SO_000305947 (another child of the 2nd level)
--SO_000034169 (child of the 3rd level in hierarchy)
SO_00033752
-SO_000048333
--SO_000033807
---SO_000030934
----SO_000253386
-----SO_3-23773

Any help is highly appreciated! I'm still learning XSLT.

Comment: I don't understand your description. Please edit your question and provide a step-by-step algorithm for determining the sort order (assume you are explaining this to a stupid person who will perform the task manually). -- Also state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: This is still not clear. Do you want to list all nodes at the same level in a contiguous block, or do you want a child listed immediately after its parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a question of *sorting* as such, but rather *nesting* records according to their hierarchy - even though you have indicated a flat file as the expected output.

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="child" match="Additional_Information" use="ParentOrgID" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', 'TOP_MOST_ORG')"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Additional_Information">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', OrgID)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```